# node server overwriting entire react dom on api request

Tags: reactjs

Been coding along i find that everytime i send a json object to my react the entire react dom is overwriten by that json from the node server

**my node server js file looks like**

```
/// sending the api request to the react app

app.use("/home", (req, res) => {
  res.json([
    {
      id: "08204230403",
      title: "Computer Programmer",
      name: "Jonathan Woze",
      proffession: "App Developer",
      salary: "4,501",
      date: "04 February 2022",
    },
  ]);
});
```

**my react js dom file looks like**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const Home = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  const getData = async () => {
    let url = "/home";
    let urlData = await fetch(url);
    let items = await urlData.json();
    setValue(items);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="logout">
        <a href="/login">Logout</a>
      </div>
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      {value.map((result) => {
        return (
          <>
            <p>{result}</p>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**my setup proxy middleware file look like**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.post(
    "/login",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:3001",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
  app.get(
    "/home",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:3001",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

**im new to node please help**